# Display Userform in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I am trying to display a form (Progress Bar) on a word document. But keep getting an error:  Run-time error 424 Object required when it gets to 'ufProgress.Show'.

```
Dim j As Long
Dim pctdone As Single

ufProgress.Show            
ufProgress.LabelProgress.Width = 0
        
For j = 1 To intPageCount

pctdone = j / intPageCount
With ufProgress
    .LabelCaption.Caption = "Processing Row " & j & " of " & intPageCount
    .LabelProgress.Width = pctdone * (.FrameProgress.Width)
End With
```

Comment: Assuming that your userform is named `ufProgress`... Where do you create the userform object?  I would expect to see a statement like `Dim progressBar As ufProgress` and then `Set progressBar = New ufProgress`. Then you can `progressBar.Show`.

Comment: This is my first time using VBA in Word.  The userform 'ufProgress' is already created and formatted within the document.  When the word document loads it runs a bunch of other code that imports a text file, removes a bunch or characters and copies/pastes individual pages into another document.  All of this works but takes several minutes to run so I wanted to add a progress bar so the user can see the progress.  The above code is right before the copy/paste code starts, but when it gets to that code I get the error.

Comment: I tried what you said, but I can't "Dim progressBar As ufProgress" because I get a compile error.  I'm guessing you meant "Dim progressBar As Object"?  Either way, I still get the same error.

Comment: PeterT meant what he wrote. The fact you are getting compile errors related to `ufProgress` suggests that it doesn't exist in the same project as your code.